# Insert values into the table with following condition :

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables
Table A with columns Name, ID
eg :

```
Name        ID
Arun       xyz
Mithila    acs
Ajay       bid
```

Table B with columns Name, Surname

eg :

```
Name      Surname
Arun      Kashyap
Mithila   Sharma
```

The third table C that I want to populate should look like :

```
Name       Surname
Arun       Kashyap
Mithila    Sharma
Ajay       Ajay
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left join` and `coalesce` as follows:

```
insert into tablec (name, surname)
select t1.name, coalesce(t2.surname,t1.name)
  from tablea t1 left join tableb t2
    on t1.name = t2.name;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what logic you want.  Here is an alternative interpretation:

```
select b.name, b.surname
from b
union all
select a.name, a.name
from b
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.name = a.name);
```